# slime-fancy not loading with emacs sbcl slime windows configuration

Tags: windows, emacs, slime, sbcl

I have slime with sbcl working in emacs 24.1 but can not get a slime repl to open.

I can use M-x slime to make a connection to sbcl in a *inferior-lisp* buffer but I can not invoke the slime-repl or get a nice lisp auto-indent when editing lisp files even though I am loading the slime-fancy contrib in .emacs.  I don't get any error messages during start-up.

When I try M-x slime-repl I get [No match].

my .emacs file:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
(add-to-list 'load-path "c:/home/bin/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")
(require 'slime)
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

I used this method for the installation:

http://www.pchristensen.com/blog/articles/installing-sbcl-emacs-and-slime-on-windows-xp

I have noticed a pattern that almost everything I try with Python and Clojure works as described and almost nothing I try related to common lisp works.  I have also tried cusp with eclipse.  I am willing to try yet another approach if there is something more recent for common lisp in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with Sujoy's answer and trimming it down to get it to work, I realized my original problem was caused by the `(require 'slime)` statement. The following .emacs file gets the slime repl to open as expected.

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

Answer (score 0):

Only 'slime-fancy will not setup the REPL. Try the below snippet. Put it in a buffer and eval.
Of course, you do not need to setup the hyperspec root as well, but that helps a lot :)

EDIT: missed out on the autoloads I am using, so here's the full config.

the keybinding (using minor-mode keymap, global mapping can be used just as easily)

```
(define-key my-keys-map (kbd "<f5>") 'slime)
```

the autoloads

```
;; slime mode
(autoload 'slime "my-slime" "Slime mode." t)
(autoload 'slime-connect "my-slime" "Slime mode." t)
```

Here's my-slime.el

```
(provide 'my-slime)
(eval-after-load "slime"
     (setq slime-lisp-implementations
     (slime-setup '(slime-asdf
                    slime-autodoc
                    slime-editing-commands
                    slime-fancy
                    slime-fontifying-fu
                    slime-fuzzy
                    slime-indentation
                    slime-mdot-fu
                    slime-package-fu
                    slime-references
                    slime-repl
                    slime-sbcl-exts
                    slime-scratch
                    slime-xref-browser))
     (slime-autodoc-mode)
     (setq slime-complete-symbol*-fancy t
           slime-complete-symbol-function 'slime-fuzzy-complete-symbol
           slime-when-complete-filename-expand t
           slime-truncate-lines nil
           slime-autodoc-use-multiline-p t)
     (add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (slime-mode t)))))
(require 'slime)
```

Comment: Result:
(slime-autodoc-mode)progn: Symbol's function definition is void: slime-autodoc-mode.    
If I remove (slime-autodoc-mode) the error goes away, but when I m-X slime I get: apply: Spawning child process: invalid argument

Comment: yea, right i missed out on the autoloads, checkout the edited answer, should work since that's what i am currently running :)